# How to get a return value from a custom confirmation box

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, confirm, confirmation

I'm trying to get a return value from a custom confirmation box base on which button a user clicks. Not sure how to go about it asynchronously.

The template for the confirmation window is premade, and the `confirmation_box()` assigns text to the specified elements.

If the user clicks yes, I want to return a value of 1/true, which would allow me to proceed with the next step. If no is clicked, the confirmation window will simply close and the code stop there.

```js
async function confirmation_box(msg = 'Are you sure?', false_btn = 'No', true_btn = 'Yes') {

  let confirmation_modal = document.getElementById('overlay');
  let true_el = confirmation_modal.querySelector('.true_btn');
  let false_el = confirmation_modal.querySelector('.false_btn');

  // assign text to elements
  confirmation_modal.querySelector('#confirmation_msg').textContent = msg;
  true_el.textContent = true_btn;
  false_el.textContent = false_btn;

  confirmation_modal.classList.add('show');

  true_el.addEventListener('click', await
    function() {
      confirmation_modal.classList.remove('show');
      return 1;
    });

  false_el.addEventListener('click', await
    function() {
      confirmation_modal.classList.remove('show');
      return 0;
    });
}


async function delete_demo() {
  let result = await confirmation_box('are you sure you want to delete this?');
  console.log(`Confirmation result ${result}`);

  if (result) {
    document.getElementById('demo_text').remove();
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

#overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  place-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#overlay.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <p id='demo_text'>Demo text</p>

    <button onclick='delete_demo()'>Delete Demo</button>


    <div id="overlay">
      <div class="modal">
        <p id="confirmation_msg"></p>

        <div>
          <button class="false_btn"></button>
          <button class="true_btn"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The return value of an event listener isn't used for anything.

Comment: You shouldn't add event listeners inside event listeners. Every time you click on the Delete button, it adds another listener to each of the true and false buttons.

Comment: Have you considered using something like Boostrap or jQuery-UI modal dialogs?

Comment: You're using `await confirmation_box('...')`, but `confirmation_box` doesn't return a promise.  It should return a promise that resolves when the button is clicked.  And also as Barmar said, another event listener is being added every time you click the delete demo button.  I made that mistake not too long ago when I was working with some large amount of data, and it alerted when it saved.  So then I accidentally put the alert inside the `forEach` that iterated over the large data set and I had to wait for it to `alert` a message 1327 times.  Please don't make that same mistake :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there.

The problem is that the `confirmation_box` function doesn't return a `Promise`, so your `await confirmation_box` statement doesn't do the waiting that you expected it to do.  The fixed code has three changes.

1. `confirmation_box` returns a `Promise` with all of the code inside the promise.
2. `return 0` and `return 1` were changed to `resolve(0)` and `resolve(1)`
3. As Barmar said, don't use `addEventListener` inside anything that might loop when you don't want multiple event listeners.  I just changed it to an `onclick` since it uses the `resolve` function available inside the `Promise` area.

Here's the fixed code:

```js
async function confirmation_box(msg = 'Are you sure?', false_btn = 'No', true_btn = 'Yes') {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      let confirmation_modal = document.getElementById('overlay');
      let true_el = confirmation_modal.querySelector('.true_btn');
      let false_el = confirmation_modal.querySelector('.false_btn');

      // assign text to elements
      confirmation_modal.querySelector('#confirmation_msg').textContent = msg;
      true_el.textContent = true_btn;
      false_el.textContent = false_btn;

      confirmation_modal.classList.add('show');

      true_el.onclick = function() {
          confirmation_modal.classList.remove('show');
          resolve(1);
        };

      false_el.onclick = function() {
          confirmation_modal.classList.remove('show');
          resolve(0);
        };
    });
}


async function delete_demo() {
  let result = await confirmation_box('are you sure you want to delete this?');
  console.log(`Confirmation result ${result}`);

  if (result) {
    document.getElementById('demo_text').remove();
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

#overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  place-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#overlay.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <p id='demo_text'>Demo text</p>

    <button onclick='delete_demo()'>Delete Demo</button>


    <div id="overlay">
      <div class="modal">
        <p id="confirmation_msg"></p>

        <div>
          <button class="false_btn"></button>
          <button class="true_btn"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahh ok, good to know about the added event listener. Thank you so much for the info and the guidance!!

Comment: @Edwards: Just for clarification - this is not an event listener.  I have just added a promise so that your code *waits* for a button to be clicked.  I have only changed the event listeners so they don't keep getting added, but the real solution here is the promise.  Here's [more about promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) on MDN.  You are welcome anyways!